# Linux bash script with arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to write a bash Script to launch a process with arguments.

As the following example: in the terminal i would launch the process and it will ask to chose a number. 
In terminal it would be :

```
user@u11:~$ process -someflag -someflag 
Hello ! Choose an option
1.blabla
2.do that
3.do the other

>>
```

Now, i want to launch the process with already the option selected in it but i couldn't succeed.

I can write this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#script.sh

process -someflag -someflag
```

If i run this script it will send me to the menu and make me choose a number. I want to provide this number inside the script. Is there any possibility ?

Comment: There is a possibility. Have you tried searching for something like "passing arguments to bash script"?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/192249/2988730?

Comment: No, this do not answer my question because we cannot pass the arguments 1 or 2 or 3 to the process i am talking about before we have launched it and the menu has been displayed...

Comment: I think you can automate this with an `expect` script.

Comment: You question is unclear, do you ultimately want to launch your process with the options listed, e.g. if the user chooses `1.` you want `process --blabla`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should do, is to look for some extra flags for `process` to make it non-interactive/start it in batch mode.

If that is not supported. You may pipe the input to `process`.

```
choice=2
echo "$choice" | process -someflag -someflag
```

Or for multiple questions:

```
# Quesions 1
choice_1=3

# Quesions 2
choice_2=4

(echo "$choice_1"; echo "$choice_2") | process -someflag -someflag
```

But that is something you should try to avoid as the interface is designed for humans it is most likely not stable. (Order of questions/answers may change)

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit. It was just something that jumped out at me.